# Using Jquery Selectors (checkbox) execute onClick

Tags: jquery, checkbox

```
function sendValues() {
var str = $("#ryan_m").serialize();
var response = $('input[name=brand[]]:checked').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "/trying1.php?avoidcache=' + myTimestamp();",
    data: {str}
    cache: false
});
}

<form action="trying1.php?b_id=$brand_id" method="get"/></td>
     <input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="$brand_id"/>
         <input type="submit" value="Compare" id="ryan_m" method="get" />
            </form>
```

I am trying to use this Ajax request to execute upon checking the available check boxes.
Currently, This script will do exactly what I want, but I have to hit submit for it to execute.

My question:

Is there a simple way that I can execute the ajax upon clicking the check box, without hitting submit?

Comment: Your problem is solved. Please select one working answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery .submit() to submit the form on click.

```
<form action="trying1.php?b_id=$brand_id" id="myForm" method="get"/></td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" class="myCheckbox" value="$brand_id"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Compare" id="ryan_m" method="get" />
</form>
```

Give you form an ID and give the checkbox a class or if you want an ID if there's only one. Then in your jquery.

```
function sendValues() {
    var str = $("#ryan_m").serialize();
    var response = $('input[name=brand[]]:checked').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/trying1.php?avoidcache=' + myTimestamp();",
        data: {str}
        cache: false
    });
 }

$('.myCheckbox').change(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit(function(){
        sendValues();
        return false; 
    });
});
```

I haven't tested out the code, but thats the idea you going for.

Comment: Why firing unnecessary events?

Comment: This does not work, In fact, It does not call the Page at all without clicking the submit button, which is what I do not want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  $("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: What is target? ;)
And what if the checkbox is (un)ticked by keyboard?

Comment: target was meant to be filled in by the user. He didn't add a class to his checkboxes so I just put target. Anyway RPM I edited the code to use input with type checkbox. You can try that. Also .click might need to be .change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name=brand[]]").change(function() {
    sendValues();
    alert("Data is sent."); // Remove this - Just for testing purpose
});
```

[jQuery Change Event](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
This detects all kinds of changes to all kinds of `<input>`. `<select>` and `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[name="brand[]"]').change(function() {
        sendValues();  
    });
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/JtBe2/

Comment: You're only detecting clicks. BUt no changes via keyboard or other scripts.